# T-SQL : Capturing multiple changes during the day but eliminating duplicates

Tags: t-sql

I needed Capture multiple changes during the day but eliminating duplicates if occurs immediately.
   Below is the snippet of sample data. 
    Source Data:

```
SEQ_ID  ID  LastName    FirstName   Updated_Time
50  1010    A   A   01/06/2016 10:00
51  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 11:00
52  1010    C   C   01/06/2016 12:00
53  1010    D   D   01/06/2016 15:00
54  1010    D   D   01/06/2016 17:00
55  1010    D   D   01/06/2016 18:00
56  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 20:00
57  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 21:00
58  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 22:00
59  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 23:00
100 2020    X   X   01/06/2016 10:00
202 3030    TTT TTT 01/06/2016 10:00
201 3030    UUU UUU 01/06/2016 11:00
203 3030    VVV VVV 01/06/2016 12:00
210 3030    UUU UUU 01/06/2016 15:00
302 4000    KQ  KQ  01/06/2016 07:00
300 4000    KQ  KQ  01/06/2016 08:00
301 4000    KQ  KQ  01/06/2016 09:00
303 4000    KQ  KQ  02/06/2016 08:00


Result should be as below :         
SEQ_ID  ID  LastName    FirstName   Updated_Time
50  1010    A   A   01/06/2016 10:00
51  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 11:00
52  1010    C   C   01/06/2016 12:00
53  1010    D   D   01/06/2016 15:00
56  1010    B   B   01/06/2016 20:00
100 2020    X   X   01/06/2016 10:00
202 3030    TTT TTT 01/06/2016 10:00
201 3030    UUU UUU 01/06/2016 11:00
203 3030    VVV VVV 01/06/2016 12:00
210 3030    UUU UUU 01/06/2016 15:00
302 4000    KQ  KQ  01/06/2016 07:00
```

This is query I could come up with:

```
 SELECT 
           [ID]
          ,[LastName]
          ,[FirstName]
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, [Updated_Time])
                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, 
                        CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(
                             ID
                             ,[LastName]
                             ,[FirstName]
                                )) AS binary(32)) ORDER BY ID ASC, [Updated_Time] ASC) [DWRecordGroupID]
        FROM 
    xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx
    order by ID , [Updated_Time] asc
```

Result of the Query:

```
 ID LastName FirstName  DWRecordGroupID
1010    A   A   0
1010    B   B   1
1010    C   C   2
1010    D   D   3
1010    D   D   3
1010    D   D   3
1010    B   B   5
1010    B   B   5
1010    B   B   5
1010    B   B   5
2020    X   X   0
3030    TTT TTT 0
3030    UUU UUU 1
3030    VVV VVV 2
3030    UUU UUU 2
4000    KQ  KQ  0
4000    KQ  KQ  0
4000    KQ  KQ  0
4000    KQ  KQ  0

The idea is to eliminate duplicated based on ID and DWRecordGroupID. But somehow I am missing at the below part where the query gives me same group number and one of them gets eliminated randomly, which is incorrect.

  ID    LastName FirstName  DWRecordGroupID

    3030    TTT TTT 0
    3030    UUU UUU 1
    3030    VVV VVV 2
    3030    UUU UUU 2
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exatly is duplicate here ? When the same firstname and last name are one after another?

Comment: Sorry if was not clear. For example : 
50 1010 A A 01/06/2016 10:00
51 1010 B B 01/06/2016 11:00
52 1010 C C 01/06/2016 12:00
53 1010 D D 01/06/2016 15:00
54 1010 D D 01/06/2016 17:00
55 1010 D D 01/06/2016 18:00
56 1010 B B 01/06/2016 20:00
57 1010 B B 01/06/2016 21:00
58 1010 B B 01/06/2016 22:00
59 1010 B B 01/06/2016 23:00

Comment: For example ID = 1010 
the result should be as below

SEQ_ID ID LastName FirstName Updated_Time
50 1010 A A 01/06/2016 10:00
51 1010 B B 01/06/2016 11:00
52 1010 C C 01/06/2016 12:00
53 1010 D D 01/06/2016 15:00
56 1010 B B 01/06/2016 20:00

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this (X1 is your table):

```
SELECT ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, UPDATED_TIME FROM (
    SELECT ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, UPDATED_TIME           
              , LAG(LAST_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATED_TIME, SEQ_ID) AS LNAME_prec               
              , LAG(FIRST_NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATED_TIME, SEQ_ID) AS FNAME_prec                
            FROM X1
    ) X2
    WHERE (LAST_NAME <>LNAME_prec AND FIRST_NAME <>FNAME_prec) OR (LNAME_prec IS NULL)
```

Output:

```
    ID          LAST_NAME  FIRST_NAME UPDATED_TIME
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
1010        A          A          2016-06-01 10:00:00.000
1010        B          B          2016-06-01 11:00:00.000
1010        C          C          2016-06-01 12:00:00.000
1010        D          D          2016-06-01 15:00:00.000
1010        B          B          2016-06-01 20:00:00.000
2020        X          X          2016-06-01 10:00:00.000
3030        TTT        TTT        2016-06-01 10:00:00.000
3030        UUU        UUU        2016-06-01 11:00:00.000
3030        VVV        VVV        2016-06-01 12:00:00.000
3030        UUU        UUU        2016-06-01 15:00:00.000
4000        KQ         KQ         2016-06-01 07:00:00.000
```

Comment: What if we have many columns. Do you prefer comparing each and every column? That was the idea behind using hash algorithm. But somehow I cant get it work with the above logic.

Comment: :). Agreed. My bad! Here is the problem, I have many source tables where we I need to eliminate duplicate records if they occur next to each other and then do Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2. My query was the initial step to identify the DWGroupId based on the changes and then do the rest. Currently I do not have source data so I had to mock-up some data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this based on your hint and it works.

 select * from 
 (
 SELECT *,
  LAG(HashValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Updated_Time], SEQ_ID) AS HashValue_Prev      
 FROM (
    SELECT ID, [LastName], [FirstName], [Updated_Time], SEQ_ID, 
 CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(
             ID
        ,[LastName]
       ,[FirstName]
       )) AS binary(32)) as HashValue          
            FROM Xxxxx as HashValue
    ) X1
 ) X2
    WHERE (HashValue <>HashValue_Prev ) OR (HashValue_Prev IS NULL)

However, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

This will obviously need to be adapted to incorporate however many columns you have in your table:

```
;WITH cte ( rownum, seq_id, id, last_name, first_name, updated_time )
     AS (SELECT row_number()
                    OVER (
                        ORDER BY id, updated_time),
                seq_id,
                id,
                last_name,
                first_name,
                updated_time
           FROM @tbl)
SELECT t.*
  FROM cte l 
       INNER JOIN @tbl t ON l.seq_id = t.seq_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cte p ON l.rownum - 1 = p.rownum
                            AND l.id = p.id
                            AND l.last_name = p.last_name
                            AND l.first_name = p.first_name
 WHERE p.seq_id IS NULL
```

The real difficulty comes from the fact that, in the end, you have to compare every non-sequence field (i.e. not seq_id and not updated_time) from one row against every non-sequence field from another row.

Note: This solution naively assumes changes to a particular ID are to be treated as a single collection of changes. So if seq_id 548 that comes in on 01/23/2017 for id 1010 has the same first_name, last_name as seq_id 56, it will not be picked up. It could be adapted to work IF the seq_id column could be guaranteed to be in sequence order (but your sample data did not have that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_number() and get the values of 1

```
;with CTE as (
select *, RowN = row_number() over (partition by lastname order by seq_id) from #yourduplicates
)  select * from cte where RowN = 1
```

Your Input table:

```
create table #yourDuplicates (Seq_ID int, id int, lastname varchar(10), firstname varchar(10), updated_time datetime)

insert into #yourDuplicates 
(SEQ_ID , ID ,  LastName  ,  FirstName  , Updated_Time ) values
  ( 50  , 1010  ,'A  ', 'A  ', '01/06/2016 10:00')
, ( 51  , 1010  ,'B  ', 'B  ', '01/06/2016 11:00')
, ( 52  , 1010  ,'C  ', 'C  ', '01/06/2016 12:00')
, ( 53  , 1010  ,'D  ', 'D  ', '01/06/2016 15:00')
, ( 54  , 1010  ,'D  ', 'D  ', '01/06/2016 17:00')
, ( 55  , 1010  ,'D  ', 'D  ', '01/06/2016 18:00')
, ( 56  , 1010  ,'B  ', 'B  ', '01/06/2016 20:00')
, ( 57  , 1010  ,'B  ', 'B  ', '01/06/2016 21:00')
, ( 58  , 1010  ,'B  ', 'B  ', '01/06/2016 22:00')
, ( 59  , 1010  ,'B  ', 'B  ', '01/06/2016 23:00')
, ( 100 , 2020  ,'X  ', 'X  ', '01/06/2016 10:00')
, ( 202 , 3030  ,'TTT', 'TTT', '01/06/2016 10:00')
, ( 201 , 3030  ,'UUU', 'UUU', '01/06/2016 11:00')
, ( 203 , 3030  ,'VVV', 'VVV', '01/06/2016 12:00')
, ( 210 , 3030  ,'UUU', 'UUU', '01/06/2016 15:00')
, ( 302 , 4000  ,'KQ ', 'KQ ', '01/06/2016 07:00')
, ( 300 , 4000  ,'KQ ', 'KQ ', '01/06/2016 08:00')
, ( 301 , 4000  ,'KQ ', 'KQ ', '01/06/2016 09:00')
, ( 303 , 4000  ,'KQ ', 'KQ ', '02/06/2016 08:00')
```